How do you use the query context parameter(of getServerSideProps), after next js 13?
I am new to web development and am following this tutorial:its pretty old and hence uses older version of next js. He uses getServerSideProps which is depreciated, and throws an error when I use it in app router.
export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  try {
    const communityDocRef = doc(firestore,"communities",context.query.communityId as string);
    const communityDoc = await getDoc(communityDocRef);

    return {
      props: {
        communityData: communityDoc.exists()
          ? JSON.parse(
              safeJsonStringify({ id: communityDoc.id, ...communityDoc.data() })
            )
          : "",
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getServerSideProps error", error);
  }
}

My understanding is that I can now call async await on any function and doesn't have to be getServerSideProps which I did, but in the tutorial he uses the context.query parameter of getServerSideProps for the query string which I need, how would I implement it without getServerSideProps.
export async function getData()
{
    const communityDocRef = doc(firestore, "communities", context.query.communityId as string)
    const communityDoc = await getDoc(communityDocRef);
    return communityData: communityDoc.data()
}


How would I get the query here?, as of now it doesn't recognize context.

Yes, getServerSideProps is no longer supported to fetch data in Next.js App Router. For cleaner data fetching logic, especially if you're interacting with a database, try creating a dedicated API route like (pages/api/communities/[communityId].js) to handle the Firebase interaction.
Sample code here:
import { firestore } from '../../lib/firebase'; // Adjust path

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { communityId } = req.query;  // get the community id

  try {
    const communityDocRef = firestore.doc(`communities/${communityId}`);
    const communityDoc = await communityDocRef.get();

    if (communityDoc.exists) {
      res.status(200).json({ id: communityDoc.id, ...communityDoc.data()});
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Community not found' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching community:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}

Let me know if this helps.
